# A multidimensional array with systematic selected elements in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

The wished output is a lot of array that looks like this:

```
public decimal [] array 1 = {1, 1, 0, 0, 0};
public decimal [] array 2 = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
public decimal [] array 3 = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
public decimal [] array 4 = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1};
```

The dimension does not fit my problem, because the problem demands a array of 14 elements, but the idear is the same. The question is how do I create this in a smart way. I tried a "for loop" creating `array 1`, but as the loop carried on it overwrote `array 1` with `array 2`:

```
class Program
{
  public decimal[] array_1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  public void Main(string[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                array_1 [i] = 1;
                array_1 [i + 1] = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 1)
            {
                array_1[i] = 1;
                array_1[i + 1] = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 2)
            {
                array_1[i] = 1;
                array_1[i + 1] = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 3)
            {
                array_1[i] = 1;
                array_1[i + 1] = 1;
            }
            else if (i == 4)
            {
                array_1[i] = 1;
                array_1[i + 1] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the above is a array with only ones and not four different arrays as firstly wished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
decimal[][] arrays = { array_1, array_2, array_3, array_4 };
for (int a = 0; a < arrays.Length; a++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays[a].Length; i++) {
        arrays[a][i] = i == a || i == a+1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Or, you can create one two-dimensional array:

```
decimal[,] array = new decimal[4, 5];
for (int row = 0; row < array.GetLength(0); row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < array.GetLength(1); column++) {
        array[row, column] = column == row || column == row+1 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try you first code suggestion i get a error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point", but then I change the main from public to static the same error appears... any idears

Comment: @DUDEofDK That sounds like something completely unrelated. Maybe a misplaced } somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a *collection* (say, `decimal[][]` - jagged array) of arrays, I suggest using *Linq*:

```
  int n = 4;

  decimal[][] arrays = Enumerable.Range(1, n)
    .Select(index => Enumerable
       .Range(1, n + 1)
       .Select(x => (decimal) (x == index || x == index + 1 ? 1 : 0))
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

and then use the collection

```
  decimal array1 = arrays[0];
```

Test

```
  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arrays
    .Select(array => string.Join(" ", array)));
```

Outcome:

```
  1 1 0 0 0
  0 1 1 0 0
  0 0 1 1 0
  0 0 0 1 1
```

If you insist on *2d array*:

```
  int n = 4;

  decimal[,] arrays = new decimal[n, n + 1];

  for (int i = 0; i < arrays.GetLength(0); ++i) {
    arrays[i, i] = 1;
    arrays[i, i + 1] = 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multidimensional array:

```
class Program
{
  public decimal[,] arrayObj = new decimal[5, 5];
  public void Main(string[] args)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
     {
       arrayObj[i][i] = 1;
       arrayObj[i+1] = 1;            
    }
}
```